# Optimal Staff Scheduling - Number of Staff Required - Free Software?

Tags: excel

I have tried to use Excel Solver already..

What I have?

**Point A**

```
00:00, 01:00,...23:00

58, 79, 81, 35, 55, ... (staff required for each hour).
```

--

**Point B**

Available Shifts

```
0600 - 1500
1400 - 2100
2300 - 0700
...
```

### ..

**Point C**
Result

I want an optimal roster generator that generates..

say.. I need

```
50 staff on 0600-1500
20 staff on 1400-2100
0 staff on 2300 - 0700
35 staff on 2330 - 0730
..
etc.
```

**Total Staff Required 135.**

This is the optimal solution, say. you can't go any more below than 135 without losing a few additional heads on an hourly basis.

--

Yes. I know about Solver Can do this partly... but surely that is not optimal enough.

Is there some free software.. or online.. when I plugin Point A & Point B, it generates Point C with minimal overhead (or wastage).

Answer (score 2):

Lets Start with Point B

**Available Shifts
0600 - 1500**

0600-1500 in this shift if you want to track information about your employees you have two options either you create an excel sheet for tracking log in and log out timings for your staff and other options is to use [eworks](http://www.eworksmanager.co.uk/staff-scheduling-software.html) online staff scheduling app that will help you track your employees shift timings, breaks, Clock-In, clock-Out, reports and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a programming library, try [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner). If you're looking for an end-user application, try [TimeFinder](http://timefinder.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey.
TimeFinder - looked at it but it doesn't seem to match what I asked for. 
Drools Planner - looks like it can do what I want.. but looks very complicated for me.

I think my problem is related to linear programming... given the requirements of staff for each hour.. I want the program to find the optimal (9 hour) shift roster that requires minimal heads... that starts at any time of day.

Any further help or recommendation is appreciated.

I managed to do part of the work using Excel Solver. But, I want a better solution.

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way to get started with Planner is to copy-paste one of the examples (together with reading the reference manual). In your case, I 'd take a look at the nurse rostering example (= staff scheduling). *Prioritize using real sized data and real sized constraints above getting an optimal solution.* Unless you got a toy problem, they are not combinable.